# function wont return despite condition of the return being true

Tags: java

In a binary search on an array.

```java
private int binarySearch(int first, int last, String name){
    int middle = (first+last)/2;

    if (catalogue[middle].getName().equals(name)){
        return catalogue[middle].getNumber();
    }
    else{
        if(catalogue[middle].getName().compareTo(name) < 0){
            binarySearch(middle, last, name);
        }
        else {
            binarySearch(first, middle, name);
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

With each element in the array `catalogue` being an object `Entry` with the attribute `name` and `number`. `binarySearch` should find the `Entry` with the same `name` and return the `number` of that `Entry`.

For some reason

```
if (catalogue[middle].getName().equals(name)){
    return catalogue[middle].getNumber();
}
```

The method will only return -1 despite seemingly reaching the other return statements?

Comment: What is `catalogue`? What is the Entry class? Please show a [mcve]

Comment: By the way, you want to `return binarySearch(...)` as you recurse

Comment: @OneCricketeer sorry, in future I will do that. I was unsure on the etiquette and did not want to just paste lines and lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you should replace `<` with `>`  and use `return` from your nested `binarySearch()` call:

```java
if(catalogue[middle].getName().compareTo(name) > 0)
    return binarySearch(middle, last, name);
return binarySearch(first, middle, name);
```

Comment: This fixed the issue thank you. I knew it was something very simple I was missing.